# call function declared below

Tags: linux, shell-script, function

Is it possible to call a function which is declared below in bash?

**Example**

```
if [ "$input" = "yes" ]; then
    YES_FUNCTION
elif [ "$input" = "no" ]; then
    NO_FUNCTION
else
    exit 0;
fi

YES_FUNCTION()
{
  .....
  .....
}

NO_FUNCTION()
{
  .....
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Like others have said, you can't do that.

But if you want to arrange the code into one file so that the main program is at the top of the file, and other functions are defined below, you can do it by having a separate `main` function.

E.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

main() {
    if [ "$1" = yes ]; then
        do_task_this
    else
        do_task_that
    fi
}

do_task_this() {
    ...
} 
do_task_that() {
    ...
} 

main "$@"; exit
```

When we call `main` at the end of file, all functions are already defined. Explicitly passing `"$@"` to `main` is required to make the command line arguments of the script visible in the function.

The explicit `exit` on the same line as the call to main is not mandatory, but can be used to prevent a running script from getting messed up if the script file is modified. Without it, the shell would try to continue reading commands from the script file after `main` returns. (see [How to read the whole shell script before executing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331837))

Comment: With Bash scripts I often use `[[ ${BASH_SOURCE[0]} = "$0" ]] && Main "$@"` to call the main function so I can source it in another script without `Main` being executed. Then I can either reuse the functions or write tests to check them.

Comment: Having `main "$@"; exit` (with `exit` on the same line as `main`) is also useful as a safeguard against the file being modified while it is interpreted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "interpreted" as in executing or parsing? I thought shells parse the files and then execute the AST in memory. Can you modify a loop body in a file while a shell is executing and see the effects? I just tried that with bash and it didn't work... Oh! But it did work to add a new top-level statement while it was sleeping from a previous statement!

Comment: @JoL, what is read is not read again, and the shell will need to read and parse the whole text of a loop before starting to run it, but then after the loop returns it will carry on reading from the rest of the file at the current position (and if the file has been modified it will screw things up). If everything is in functions, the shell needs to read everything before starting to do anything (except defining those functions), if we put the `exit` on the same line as `main` we make sure the shell won't read anything again from the file after `main` returns.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I made a question on this to which your comment would be half the answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449593/is-parsing-scripts-at-script-runtime-ubiquitous-to-shells-or-present-in-other-in

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What does `main "$@"; exit` as the last line in the file do that `main "$@"` wouldn't do?  OTOH, `main "$@"; exit $?` would allow `main()` to `return` a value that would be passed as the exit status of the script, so that actually adds some value.

Comment: @MontyHarder, it doesn't matter if you use `main; exit`, `main; exit $?` or `main <EOF>`, in all cases the exit code of `main` is used as the exit code of the script. The `exit` would be just to prevent things getting messed up if someone edits the script while it's running.

Comment: @MontyHarder, see [How to read the whole shell script before executing it?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/331837)

Answer (score 22):

No, the functions have to exist in the shells environment at the time of calling them.

Google's ["Shell Style Guide"](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml?showone=main#main) has a fix for this:

> A function called `main` is required for scripts long enough to contain at least one other function.

At the very end of the script, after all functions, as the only statement not in a function, you would have

```
main "$@"
```

This would call the `main` function with whatever parameters the script was given.  The `main` function could be located at the top of the script (the style guide says to put it at the bottom, but then again, it says many things).

When the shell gets to the `main` call, all functions in the script have been parsed and can therefore be called from within the `main` function.

Answer (score 10):

No, functions have to be declared before they’re used. Shell scripts are read line by line and acted upon line by line; so a function doesn’t exist until its declaration has been executed.

Comment: your are right. the problem is I have 30+ functions in a script. it's quite tricky when we read the code. In `C` it's comfortable.

Comment: You can put your function declarations in another file and source it (`. yourfile`).

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but the requirement is to have a single script.

Comment: @SivaPrasath What's exactly the problem?  Just define all the functions, maybe even putting the main code in a function and then the last line shows which function is called and contains the main part of the script.

Comment: @SivaPrasath In C, you don't have bare `if` statements outside of a function. The function doesn't have to be defined when you *declare* the `if`-containing function, just when you *call* it.

Answer (score 4):

The shell has no concept of `declaring` a function. So you cannot have a forward declaration.

As a consequence, you need to have the function implementation read by the shell before it can be called.

Comment: Technically, some shells (ksh, zsh) have a _function autoloading_ feature which could be seen as some form of _declaration_ (where `autoload f` declares the function, but its body is only _loaded_ upon the first invocation). That doesn't apply to the OP's `bash` though.