# Where is the main function in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am using the FUNCNAME array variable that gives us various executing functions' name. While using it, I came across `main` function inside `${FUNCNAME[max_ind]}`.

Where is this `main` function defined in our shell script? What code is written inside `main` and how can I use it? Basically all the information of this `main` function.

Answer (score 14):

It's the main level of the shell script.

`FUNCNAME` itself seems specific to Bash, and its man page says this:

> An  array variable containing the names of all shell functions currently in the execution call stack.  The element with index 0 is the name of any currently-executing shell function.
> The bottom-most element (the one with the highest index) is "main".  This variable exists only when a shell function is executing.

Which means it could get confusing too, since e.g. this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
main() {
        foo
}
foo() {
        declare -p FUNCNAME;
}
main
```

would print

```
declare -a FUNCNAME=([0]="foo" [1]="main" [2]="main")
```

even though the two `main`s are not the same function.

Note that it's not that far-fetched to explicitly create a function called `main`. Having a dedicated main function might help with structuring the code, since it's probably easier to read a script where the main program is in one place and not perhaps scattered here and there on the top level between other function definitions.

There's also the idiom of putting everything in functions and calling `main "$@"; exit` on the main level to make sure that if the script file is modified during execution, it won't affect the running script. See: [How to read the whole shell script before executing it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331837/170373)

I don't know why Bash has chosen to use `main` there, instead of something that would stand out more, like the `__main__` that Python uses for a similar use.

Comment: ‘I don't know why Bash has chosen to use `main` there’: TBH, this is yet another thing on a long list of things bash does that make me immediately think ‘Why would you do that?’. Top of the list is invocation as `/bin/sh` not actually being strictly compatible with POSIX (you still get a bunch of extensions).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, having the compatibility mode still support extensions that don't clash with any standard behaviour (but would e.g. just be syntax errors in a standard shell) more like makes me think "why would one _not_ do that". But that's a discussion that seems a bit off-topic here.